# Reading and parsing xml file in golang but getting no error and "0" value while printing

Tags: go, struct

I want to read an XML and use it to create logic in the program. Currently, I am new to go, I am able to create struct from XML file but somehow not sure how to print values. Later I want to use this value as a variable in the program. Please also share tips to do it.

Below is the XML file I am using -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
<rule type="rule0">
<conditions>
   <priority>1</priority>
   <tgppmccmnc>52503</tgppmccmnc>
   <rgid>300</rgid>
   <serviceclass>null</serviceclass>
   <counterstatus0>dgu</counterstatus0>
   <counterstatus1>null</counterstatus1>
  </conditions>
  <apply>
  <chargingrulename>up_lw_normal</chargingrulename>
  <chargingrulebasename>up_lw_normal</chargingrulebasename>
   <qosinfo>
     <max_bitrate_dl>500000</max_bitrate_dl>
     <max_bitrate_ul>3000000</max_bitrate_ul>
     <qci>9</qci>
     </qosinfo>
   </apply>
    </rule>
  <rule type="rule1">
   <conditions>
   <priority>1</priority>
   <tgppmccmnc>52503</tgppmccmnc>
   <rgid>300</rgid>
   <serviceclass>null</serviceclass>
   <counterstatus0>dgu</counterstatus0>
   <counterstatus1>null</counterstatus1>
    </conditions>
   <apply>
   <chargingrulename>up_lw_normal</chargingrulename>
  <chargingrulebasename>up_lw_normal</chargingrulebasename>
   <qosinfo>
     <max_bitrate_dl>500000</max_bitrate_dl>
     <max_bitrate_ul>3000000</max_bitrate_ul>
     <qci>9</qci>
   </qosinfo>
    </apply>
   </rule>
   </rules>
```

I have created these structs :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
)

// our struct which contains the complete array of all rules in the file
type Rules struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rules"`
    Rules   []Rule   `xml:"rule"`
}

// the rule struct for all policy rules
type Rule struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"rule"`
    Type       string     `xml:"type,attr"`
    Conditions Conditions `xml:"conditions"`
    Apply      Apply      `xml:"Apply"`
    // Name string `xml:"name"`
}

// a simple struct which contains all our
// conditions
type Conditions struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"conditions"`
    Priority       uint32   `xml:"priority"`
    Tgppmccmnc     string   `xml:"tgppmccmnc"`
    Rgid           string   `xml:"rgid"`
    Serviceclass   string   `xml:"serviceclass"`
    Counterstatus0 string   `xml:"counterstatus0"`
    Counterstatus1 string   `xml:"counterstatus1"`
}

//Apply struct //It is used for applying speed and rule to Gx response
type Apply struct {
    XMLName              xml.Name `xml:"apply"`
    Chargingrulename     string   `xml:"chargingrulename"`
    Chargingrulebasename string   `xml:"chargingrulebasename"`
    Qosinfo              Qosinfo  `xml:"qosinfo"`
}

// Apply struct for QoS speed
type Qosinfo struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"qosinfo"`
    Max_bitrate_dl string   `xml:"max_bitrate_dl"`
    Max_bitrate_ul string   `xml:"max_bitrate_ul"`
    Qci            string   `xml:"qci"`
}
```

Main

```
xmlFile, err := os.Open("PolicyRules.xml")
// if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("Successfully Opened the file")
// defer the closing of our xmlFile so that we can parse it later on
defer xmlFile.Close()
// read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
// we initialize our array
var rules Rules
var rule Rule
var conditions Conditions
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &rules)
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &rule)
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &conditions)
fmt.Println(rule.Conditions.Priority)
```

Please help

Comment: You forgot to mention what the error is.

Comment: @mkopriva sorry for wrong words. Actually no error its just priniting 0

Comment: How do you know there's no error if you're not checking the errors returned by `xml.Unmarshal`?

Comment: Check **all** returned errors: `ioutil.ReadAll()`, `xml.Unmarshal()`. Always!

Comment: The first `Unmarshal` should return an error that will tell you exactly what's wrong. Also you only need to unmarshal once into `&rules`, the two other `xml.Unmarshal` calls should be omitted as the target structs don't match the content of the `byteValue` so they are bound to either return an error or produce no useful result.

Comment: @mkopriva. I added below :   if err != nil {  fmt.Println(err)  }  b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)     if err != nil {    panic(err)    }  var rules Rules      var rule Rule  err = xml.Unmarshal(b, &rules)
      if err != nil {  fmt.Println(err.Error())      }
      fmt.Println(rule.Conditions.Priority)
I got error :- xml: name "Apply" in tag of main.Rule.Apply conflicts with name "apply" in main.Apply.XMLName 0. The problem found in this struct - Apply Apply `xml:"Apply"` hence I change it to Apply Apply `xml:"apply"` . Now I am not getting any error but still value is 0

Comment: b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))  is printing proper xml file but I think I am doing unmarshalling incorrectly.

Comment: is it right way to print specific field "Priority"  err = xml.Unmarshal(b, &rules)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

fmt.Println(rule.Conditions.Priority)

Comment: You're printing the wrong value. You've unmarshaled into `rules` so you need to print the priority value by accessing it through the `rules` value. Remove `rule` and `conditions` altogether, they will not be magically populated and hence they are useless for your purposes. Print this `rules.Rules[0].Conditions.Priority`.

Comment: Also don't put large snippets of code into comments as they then become unreadable, instead update your question by adding the new code.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/qASkH4d-JEa

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva working now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the err value of `xml.Unmarshal` to debug the issue:**

```
err = xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &rules)
```

Here is the error:

> xml: name "Apply" in tag of main.Rule.Apply conflicts with name
>   "apply" in main.Apply.XMLName

Modify **Rule struct** to fix it:

```
// the rule struct for all policy rules
type Rule struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"rule"`
    Type       string     `xml:"type,attr"`
    Conditions Conditions `xml:"conditions"`
    Apply      Apply      `xml:"apply"`
    // Name string `xml:"name"`
}
```